# I invest 5000 PHp in bitcoin and to ask me i need to pay the transfer fee

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, payment

- List item

I invest 5000Php in bitcoin but after the mining my invest he ask i need to pay a transfer fee .is it normal to pay that because im from Philippine

Comment: Please answer me do i need to pay that tranfer fee to claim my profit ?

Comment: No, its a scam, you have been tricked by criminals.